# Find Normalizing constant

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

let $f(x,\theta)=C_\theta \exp(-\sqrt{x}/\theta)$ where $x$ and $\theta$ are both positive.

Find the normalising constant $C_\theta$. I get $C_\theta=\sqrt{2}/\theta$ but my book says $C_\theta=1/2\theta^2$. Who is right?

Comment: The book.  If you show us what you tried, we may be able to help you see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
u & = \sqrt{x}/\theta \\
u^2 & = x/\theta^2 \\
2u\,du & = dx/\theta^2
\end{align}

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt{x}/\theta} \, dx = \theta^2\int_0^\infty e^{-u} \Big( 2u\,du \Big) = 2\theta^2.
$$

The integral can be done by parts, thus:
$$
\int u \Big(e^{-u}\,du\Big) = \int u\,dv=uv-\int v\,du = -ue^{-u}-\int -e^{-u}\,du,\text{ etc.}
$$
Then there's the problem of finding $-ue^{-u}\Big\vert_{u=0}^{u\to\infty}$.  That can be done by L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt{x}} dx = 2$. Use the linear substitution $t ={x \over \theta^2}$ to get the scaled result.